# Como desativar um campo de texto para edição usando jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, laravel-4

Digamos que eu tenha um formulário com os campos de 1 à 7.

Algo como:

```
field-1
field-2
field-3
field-4
field-5
field-6
field-7
```

Todos esses campos estão em um formulário.

Com o Laravel, algumas vezes eu experimentei situações de quando eu desabilito um campo com a propriedade `disabled`, eu não fui capaz de recuperá-lo através do array `Input`. Assim, para evitar diretamente esse problema eu gostaria de saber se há, e se houver, como, uma forma de bloquear, via JS/jQuery, que um campo seja editado no formulário. PORÉM, apenas saberei disso (se ele deve ser desabilitado ou não) em tempo de execução.

Ex.: De acordo com o valor do campo `field-2` eu posso precisar desativar os campos `field-3`, `field-4` e `field-5` para edição, mas ainda precisarei dos seus valores no array INPUT, que serão atribuídos para ter o mesmo valor do `field-2`, nesse caso.

Não sei se consegui ser claro, mas qualquer dúvida perguntem nos comentários!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O navegador não envia campos desabilitados com `disabled` na submissão do formulário, por isso sua primeira tentativa não funcionou.

Por outro lado, você não precisa usar script para impedir a alteração de um campo. Ao invés disso, use o atributo `readonly`.

Efeitos colaterais:

- O usuário poderá, entretanto, clicar e selecionar o conteúdo do campo.
- Além disso, os estilos do campo permanecerão os originais, isto é, o usuário poderá não perceber que se trata de um campo somente-leitura. Nesse caso, adicione um estilo para manter a usabilidade, por exemplo, deixando o fundo da caixa um pouco acinzentado.

Exemplo:

```html
<input type="text" value="Valor fixo" 
    style="background: #EEE; cursor: not-allowed; color: #777" readonly />
```

Exemplo de classe CSS para reuso:

```css
.desabilitado {
    background: #EEE; 
    cursor: not-allowed; 
    color: #777;
}
```

Dessa forma você pode manter o *feedback* visual para o usuário.

Veja o exemplo funcional do código acima no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4SFy/).

#### Considerações de segurança

Alguém pode argumentar que desabilitar campos na tela não é uma boa prática do ponto de vista de Segurança da Informação, pois hoje um usuário pode facilmente burlar essa limitação através da Ferramenta do Desenvolvedor (<kbd>F12</kbd>), alterando as propriedades do campo. Isso está correto, em parte.

O importante é entender que a necessidade de desabilitar campos é parte essencial do funcionamento dos sistemas. Não é seu objetivo **garantir a segurança** da informação daquele campo.

Este artigo tem por objetivo auxiliar o desenvolvedor *front-end* com um elemento puramente visual e não isenta as validações necessárias no *back-end*.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Mas é importante ressaltar que se o usuário tem conhecimento básico de Javascript utilizando o console do navegador o usuário poderá alterar seu campo e enviar junto ao Form.

Answer (score 3):

Quando disabled é usado em um `<input type=text>` por exemplo, esse campo não pode ser resgatado pelo `$_POST/$_GET`. O adequado é usar o atributo `readonly`, isso garante que o campo seja acessível pelo php, e no HTML ele não poderá ser editado.

```html
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" readonly="readonly"  />
```

Um exemplo utilizando js puro:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function bloquearInput(){
                var input = document.getElementById('nome');
    
                if(input.readOnly){
                    input.readOnly = false;
                }else{
                    input.readOnly = true;
                }
    
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"  value="sem edição"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="bloquearInput();" value="bloquear/desbloquear">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```