# Diferença entre :disabled e :readonly em HTML?

Tags: html

Geralmente ambos possuem comportamentos similares quando renderizados no navegador.

Se eu abrir um HTML com isto:

```
<input type="text" value="tente me alterar" disabled>
<input type="text" value="tente me alterar" readonly>
```

Ambos não permitem que o usuário altere o texto, vejo o exemplo abaixo:

```html
 <input type="text" value="tente me alterar" disabled>
 <input type="text" value="tente me alterar" readonly>
```

Então, qual a diferença de fato entre os dois tipos de estados, e quando eu devo usar cada um deles?

Comment: [Pergunta  relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3897/como-desativar-um-campo-de-texto-para-edicao-usando-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Disabled** não passa o valor para o fomulário, além de não poder editar.

**Readonly** envia o valor para o formulário e também não pode editar.

Supondo que tenha esse html:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="foo" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="bar" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

Sua página '**page.php**' irá receber apenas o **`$_POST['bar']`**

Comment: Outra diferença é que o aspeto predefinido dos dois é diferente.

Answer (score 23):

`Disabled` você não pode editar nem obter o valor do input ao processar o Form.

`Readonly` você pode pelo menos pegar o valor do input no processamento do Form.

Isto é o básico. Há mais algumas nuances:

- No `Disabled` você não consegue selecionar o valor do campo para copiá-lo, diferentemente do `Readonly`;
- No `Disabled` o Tab Cursor não para no campo, diferentemente do `Readonly`;

Comment: "Pegar" o valor do input como usuário, certo? Pois programaticamente você ainda consegue ;)

Comment: Exatamente. Deixa eu melhorar isso.

Comment: Funcionou pra mim também. Valeu!

Answer (score 11):

Apenas para complementar as respostas do @mend3 e @Cigano Morrison Mendez.

Tanto disabled quanto readonly são atributos predefinidos, isto quer dizer que, eles não precisam receber valor para que funcione.

### Exemplo:

```html
Disabled:
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Apenas Disabled" disabled>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Disabled true" disabled="true">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Disabled false" disabled="false">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Disabled goku" disabled="goku">
<br>Readonly:
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Apenas readonly" readonly>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Readonly true" readonly="true">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Readonly false" readonly="false">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Readonly goku" readonly="goku">
```

Não adianta colocar false, os valores são ignorados e o atributo age como booleano, ou esta ou não esta.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> readonly
> ```
>
> Este atributo booleano indica que o usuário não pode modificar o valor
>   do controle. HTML5 Este atributo é ignorado se o valor do atributo
>   type for hidden, range, color, checkbox, radio, file ou um tipo de
>   botão.
>
> ```
> disabled
> ```
>
> Este atributo booleano indica que o controle de formulário não está
>   disponível para interação. Em particular o evento click não será
>   disparado em controles desabilitados. Além disso, o valor de um
>   controle desabilitado não é enviado com o formulário.

Fonte: [Atributos de um elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)