# Campo desabilitado não passa para o $_POST

Tags: php, ajax

Estou com problemas com o campo que eu desabilito caso uma das opções seja marcada, porém quando o campo esta como `desabled` ele não passa valores para o PHP.

Gostaria de saber como verificar se o valor existe ou não, e caso ele não exista setar como null.

Tentei fazer de varias formas porém o mesmo erro acontesce:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU

As tentativas foram:

```
   $campos[':DAT_FINAL_VINCU'] = ((isset($_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU'])) ? eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU']) : null ); 
    $campos[':DAT_FINAL_VINCU'] = strlen(eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU'])) === 0 ? null : htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_TXT_DESCR_VINCU'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $campos[':DAT_FINAL_VINCU'] = strlen(eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU'])) === null ? null : htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_TXT_DESCR_VINCU'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Como devo fazer ?

Estou colocando o campo via jQUERY porém não está funcionando olha como faço:

```
        var variavel = $('#f_FLG_STATU_VINCU').val();
    if (variavel == "A") {
        $('#f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU').val(null);
    }
    $('#f_FLG_STATU_VINCU').change(function () {

        var variavel = $(this).val();
        var today = new Date();

        if (variavel == "A") {
            $('#f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU').val(null);
            $('#f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU').prop("readonly", true);
        } else {
            $('#f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU').prop("readonly", false);
            $('#f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU').datepicker("setDate", today);
        }
    });
```

Comment: readonly passa disabled ja diz campo desativado

Comment: [diferença entre readonly e disabled](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6770/91)

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando, olha minha edição

Comment: @rray como vai ficar meu array $campos[''] ? Porque se caso o valor seja vazio preciso seta-lo como null

Comment: Verifique se o elemento do array ou o array interior for `empty`: `if(empty($array))` ou `if(empty($array['posicao']))` e seta como `null`

Comment: Vlw, funcionou !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dessa forma vai funcionar o tratamento:

```
 $campos[':DAT_FINAL_VINCU'] = array_key_exist('f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU',$_POST) && $_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU'] !== null ? eglise_dataDeDMAParaAMD($_POST['f_DAT_FINAL_VINCU']) : null ;
```

Nesse ternario estamos verificando se a chave existe no array , existindo ele verifica se o valor não é NULL.

Lembrando que sempre que for receber parametros do HTML deve-se realizar um tratamento como "htmlspecialchars ou "htmlentities" para evitar ataques como sql injection ou similares.