# Como desabilitar campo em formulário usando JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um form de cadastro onde o cliente digita o CEP por Request usando Ajax para pegar o endereço, o bairro, a cidade e o estado.
Mas como faço pra desabilitar esses campos depois que foram preenchidos com o resultado do Ajax?
Eu preciso desabilitar e habilitar os campos de acordo com a minha necessidade e não colocar em "Somente leitura".

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como desativar um campo de texto para edição usando jQuery/JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3897/como-desativar-um-campo-de-texto-para-edi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-usando-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando quiser desabilitar o campo, basta alterar `disabled` para `true` ou `false` para habilitar ou desabilitar.

```
$("#campo").prop( "disabled", true );
$("#campo").prop( "disabled", false );
```

**UPDATE:** *readonly* **vs** *disabled*

Você pode usar `readonly` ou `disabled`, ambos impedem o usuário de alterar o campo, mas `disabled` impede que o valor do campo seja usado de qualquer forma, ou seja, quando o form for enviado, o valor do campo não será enviado junto. Contudo, alguns campos, como `<SELECT>`, `<OPTION>` e  `<BUTTON>` não possuem o atributo `readonly`, por isso, usar `readonly` com esses campos não vai funcionar.

Sendo assim, você pode usar `readonly` em vez de `disabled` para campos que não são `<SELECT>`, `<OPTION>` ou `<BUTTON>`. Se tiver algum desses no teu form, pode usar `disabled` e ter um campo `hidden` que vai conter o valor do compo desabilitado do form a ser enviado junto com o form. Sendo `.campos` os campos que podem ser usados Quando quiser "desabilitar" os campos:

```
$(".campos").prop( "disabled", true );
$(".select").prop( "readonly", true );
$(".escondido").val( $(".select").val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar na success function de seu ajax

```
$('#idCampo').prop('readonly', true);
```